# Processing an uploaded file without saving it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am uploading a file using the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImportDeleteCourse(ImportFromExcel model)
{
  var excelFile = model.ExcelFile;
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     OrganisationServices services = new OrganisationServices();
     string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
                                  Path.GetFileName(excelFile.FileName));

    excelFile.SaveAs(filePath);
    // ... snipped //
  }
}
```

I do not really need to do store the uploaded excel file. Is there anyway I can process it without saving?

Note: The ImportFromExcel class is nothing but a model, which is basically:

```
  public class ImportFromExcel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Excel file to upload.")]
        [DisplayName("Excel File")]
        public HttpPostedFileWrapper ExcelFile { get; set; }
    }
```

The most interesting part is that it wraps a HttpPostedFileWrapper.

Comment: I'm new to .NET - I don't know how to do that.

Comment: what is this ImportFromExcel class? Can you show its methods, fields, whatever to give any clue? Try to list them with Reflector http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx or in Visual Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. As Patko suggested, the InputStream property can be used for another stream. For example I did this for an uploaded xml document to use with LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument XmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(viewmodel.FileUpload.InputStream))
```

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

The [HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream.aspx) property looks promising. You should be able to use that and save the data to whichever other stream you need to.